# Error when trying to upload an image to restdb

Tags: python, node.js, nosql, restdb

I am evaluating [restdb](https://restdb.io/) at the moment and using one of their limited free accounts for the evaluation. I can upload json data without issue, but when I try to upload an image I get a 403 message and the following error:
"Please register a domain to serve public routes!"

The thing is, I am not serving any public routes, so I am unsure what the message is telling me. I am using the python example they provide at:

[Python Client Image Upload Example](https://github.com/RestDB/clientexamples/tree/master/Python%20File%20Upload)

However, I get the same message with a similar client I wrote in nodejs.

I contacted them, but as yet, I cannot get a clear explanation for the issue. There is no difficulty in uploading an image directly from their interface, so it appears the functionality is supported on free accounts.

Has anyone experienced something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the ability to upload images using the API is not available on free accounts which makes it all a bit of a chocolate fireguard I guess.
The rather cryptic message "Please register a domain to serve public routes!"

Should read
"This function is not available on free accounts"

but that, of course, would be far too obvious.